# data-plugin-options filter is not working

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using this JessicaWhite free webtemplate (http://www.html5xcss3.com/2014/02/jessicawhite-responsive-html5-theme.html). I'm trying to set a filter in my image portfolio in order to show images of defined filter by default and not all images.
I've tried many things (data-plugin-options='{"filter": ".category01")'), but no luck.

HTML:

```
<ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter" data-plugin-options='{"filter": ".category01"}'>

<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="btn btn-mini selected">All</a></li>

<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".category01" class="btn btn-mini">Category01</a></li>   

<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".category02" class="btn btn-mini">Category02</a></li>

</ul>
```

I have also tried to switch ' for " within the data-plugin-options, but no luck.

Here is the JS for "option-set":

```
/* SORTING */ 

$(function(){

  var $container = $('.projects');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.element'
  });

  var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
      $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
    var options = {},
        key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
        value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
    // parse 'false' as false boolean
    value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
    options[ key ] = value;
    if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
      // changes in layout modes need extra logic
      changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
    } else {
      // otherwise, apply new options
      $container.isotope( options );
    }

    return false;
  });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the below comments, try the following:

Remove the 'data-category' attribute from your portfolio items, it's not being used.

Change your 'filter buttons' markup to the following -

```
<ul id="filters">
  <li><a class="filter-button" href="#filter" data-filter="*" class="btn btn-mini">All</a></li>
  <li><a class="filter-button" href="#filter" data-filter=".category01" class="btn btn-mini selected">Category01</a></li>
  <li><a class="filter-button" href="#filter" data-filter=".category02" class="btn btn-mini">Category02</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment out the entire "sorting" JS function and replace with this -

```
var $projects = $('.projects').isotope({
  filter: '.category 01'
});

$('.filter-button').on( 'click', function() {
  var filteredVal = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $projects.isotope({ filter: filteredVal });
  $('.filter-button.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Hi Donny, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately changing the filters to options didn't help. Do you think the JS file should be modified as per the remark "make option object dynamically"?

Comment: There definitely could be some shenanigans happening there that'd cause this issue. As a first step, try commenting out the line inside the "else" statement towards the end: $container.isotope( options );.  That should at least tell us if the filtering will work as intended upon the initial load.  If so, then we'll need to change some JS in that area to enable filtering when a user clicks the links.

Comment: When I commented out as suggested, then the manual filtering (clicking by mouse cursor) doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Correct... but did the portfolio initially load with the "category 01" filter applied?

Comment: Nope, still "all."

Comment: Okedoke, in that case I'd bet on the problem being in your "portfolio" markup.  The JS is looking for a container element with class "projects", which has at least one direct child element with class " category 01".  Can you confirm that this lines up with your markup structure?  Make sure any items with the "category 01" class are direct children of the "projects" element... IE- if you have an image inside of a div, the div should have class "category 01", not the image.  Also take a look at your console, seeing any " undefined " errors?

Comment: I have it like this:                    <div class="projects">     
                        <div class="span3 element category01" data-category="category01">
                            <div class="hover_img">
                                <img src="Image1.jpg" alt="" />
                                <span class="portfolio_zoom"><a href="Image1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[portfolio1]"></a></span>
                            </div> 
                        </div>

Comment: Good deal, I'm going to update my answer above with a couple of things to do that should get this working.

Comment: Donny, you are a star and saved my nervous! It's working like a charm. Many thanks! :-) I don't want to bother you anymore, but could you direct me how I could add pagination? I have for example 50 images per category, so pagination would help a lot.

Comment: Glad to help, John!  Please mark my answer as accepted if it was a good fix.  As to pagination, that's a bit of a different animal.  Isotope, the sorting/filtering library you're using, can't do both filtering and pagination at the same time...it can only filter elements that already exist and are loaded at the time it's initialized.  Instead of a pagination system, I'd suggest you look in to lazy loading the images...delaying their load until they are in (or near) the viewport.  There are a number of ways to go about this, but I'd recommend Lazysizes for ease of use....

Comment: Install this: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes.  Then you'll need to change all of your IMG tag 'src' attributes to 'data-src', and add class 'lazyload' to every IMG element.  That should work pretty much out of the box for a big performance improvement.

Comment: I will do so. Thank you again for your help!